# endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org3.example.com:7051

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to adding an org3 to an lanuched fabric-network based this tutorials:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channel_update_tutorial.html

but when I execute this command finally 

`peer channel join -b mychannel.block`

it appears this error:

`Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org3.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded`

when I look the logs :

`docker logs -f peer0.org1.example.com`

it seems right:

`2018-10-12 02:18:29.902 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 032 Installed Chaincode [mycc] Version [1.0] to peer
2018-10-12 02:18:52.555 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleStateUpdates -> INFO 033 Channel [mychannel]: Handling LSCC state update for chaincode [mycc]
2018-10-12 02:18:52.571 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 034 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [3] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-12 02:18:53.785 UTC [golang-platform] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 035 building chaincode with ldflagsOpt: '-ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags '-static'"'
2018-10-12 02:18:53.785 UTC [golang-platform] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 036 building chaincode with tags: 
2018-10-12 02:19:17.969 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 037 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-12 02:21:56.351 UTC [gossip/gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 038 Anchor peer with same endpoint, skipping connecting to myself
2018-10-12 02:21:56.404 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 039 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [5] with 1 transaction(s)`

so I want to ask why appears this question and how can I solve this problm? many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with Hyperledger Fabric V1.4. I seems like the problem is with GOLANG. Add this 'GODEBUG=netdns=go' to your  environment variables. I hope this helps.

```
 peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
```